# ForeignObjects not working with Safari and D3

Tags: d3.js, svg, safari

I have a D3 Force Layout that works fine on FireFox and Chrome but none of the foreign objects that I append to the SVG nodes for labels appear in the Safari Browser. The code is below. What is wrong? When I look the foreign objects in the FireFox/Chrome inspectors, it shows the html that I append to the foreign object. But when I look in the Safari inspector, the html isn't there at all.

**EDIT:** here is a [simplified jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MattSL/yx1eo8xt/3/) of the problem. If you open it in Chrome or Firefox, it works fine. If you open it in Safari, it doesn't.

```
      nodeTxt = svg.selectAll(".nodetxt")
           .data(nodeTxtData)
           .enter()
           .append("foreignObject")
           .attr("class", "nodeTxt")
           .attr({
             "width": function(d) { return d.radius; },
             "height": function(d) { return d.radius; }
           })
           .style({
              "font-size": function(d) { return d.radius/4 + "px";},
              "border-radius": function(d) { return d.count * 2;},
              "-webkit-border-radius": function(d) { return d.count * 2;},
              "-moz-border-radius": function(d) { return d.count * 2;},
              "position": "relative",
              "pointer-events": "none"
           })
           .html(function(d) {
              var uID = d.name.replace(/([.*+?^=!;:$%&'," "{}()|\-[\]\/\\])/g, "").substring(0,25);
              if (uID !== null) {
              return '<div class="htmlDiv" id=' + uID + ' style="width:' + d.count * 4 + 'px; height:' + d.count * 4 + 'px;' +
                 'border-radius:' + d.count * 2 + 'px;' + '-webkit-border-radius:' + d.count * 2 + 'px;' +
                 '-moz-border-radius:' + d.count * 2 + 'px;">' + d.name + '</div>';
              } else {
                console.log(d);
                return '<div id="bad"></div>';
              }
           })
           .attr({
              "transform": function(d) {
                 var uID = d.name.replace(/([.*+?^=!;:$%&'," "{}()|\-[\]\/\\])/g, "").substring(0,25);
                 if(uID !== null){
                var w1 = (parseInt(d3.select(this).style("width"), 10) / 2),
                      w2 = d.count * 2,
                      y = -d.count * 2,
                      x = (w1 > w2) ? -w1 : -w2;
                 return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")";
               } else {
                 return "translate(0,0)";
               }
              },
              "opacity": 1
           });
```

Comment: I think safari needs -webkit-transform rather than transform.

Comment: That doesn't seem to make a difference. I just tried it with the prefix and it didn't work and then I tried it without any transform and that doesn't fix the problem either. Then I tried it again as I have it above but I added a border to the foreignObject and its in the correct place. It's just that there is nothing actually in the foriegn object.

Comment: Can you post a working example of the problem? We use foreignObject with simple constant values and it seems to work fine in Safari, and the fact that the HTML isn't even there indicates to me that something is going wrong earlier in the chain.

Comment: Ok, here is an example that works in Chrome and Firefox but not Safari: https://jsfiddle.net/MattSL/yx1eo8xt/3/

Comment: Acording to the spec there should be an `xmlns` attribute to set the namespace for the contents of the foriegnobject: `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit old, but I hope this could help:

Adding `position: fixed` to the element inside `foreignObject` solves the positioning, but not the scale. To solve the scale I added this:

```
d3.zoom().on('zoom', event => {
    // zoom stuff...
    const isSafari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    if (isSafari) {
        d3.selectAll(NODE_SELECTOR).style('transform', `scale(${transform.k})`);
    }
});
```

Also the element inside `foreignObject` should have: `transform-origin: 0px 0px`